# Using JSON object values in javascript to change values for another JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement

So I'm trying to use values in a JSON object (Object A) to check if another object (Object B) will show or not. I can't just instantiate the information due to the other data sets, right? So I have this:

```
if (data['Date-Returned-to-work'].day.placeholder == "--" &&
data['Date-Returned-to-work'].month.placeholder) == "--" &&
data['Date-Returned-to-work'].year.placeholder) == '----") {
    show = 'false';
}else {
    show = 'true';
}
```

However, it isn't changing the value when placed in Object B's spot for conditional statements. Here's a section Object A.

```
"label": "Date Returned to work (if not returned to work, please explain & detail expected return to work date)",
                "hideInputLabels": false,
                "inputsLabelPosition": "top",
                "fields": {
                    "day": {
                        "placeholder": "--",
                        "hide": false,
                        "type": "number",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "month": {
                        "placeholder": "--",
                        "hide": false,
                        "type": "select",
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "year": {
                        "placeholder": "----",
                        "hide": false,
                        "type": "number",
                        "required": true
                    }
                },
                "useLocaleSettings": false,
                "mask": false,
                "tableView": true,
                "alwaysEnabled": false,
                "type": "day",
                "input": true,
                "key": "Date-Returned-to-work",
                "validate": {
                    "customMessage": "",
                    "json": ""
                },
                "conditional": {
                    "show": "",
                    "when": "",
                    "json": ""
                },
                "encrypted": false,
                "maxDate": "",
                "minDate": "",
                "properties": {},
                "customConditional": "",
                "logic": [],
                "attributes": {},
                "tags": [],
                "reorder": false
            }
```

and here is Object B

```
                "label": "if not returned",
                "allowMultipleMasks": false,
                "showWordCount": false,
                "showCharCount": false,
                "tableView": true,
                "alwaysEnabled": false,
                "type": "textfield",
                "input": true,
                "key": "if-not-returned",
                "defaultValue": "",
                "validate": {
                    "customMessage": "",
                    "json": ""
                },
                "conditional": {
                    "show": "",
                    "when": "",
                    "json": "",
                    
                },
                "properties": {},
                "tags": [],
                "inputFormat": "plain",
                "encrypted": false,
                "customConditional": "if (data['Date-Returned-to-work'].day.placeholder === \"--\" &&\r\n    data['Date-Returned-to-work'].month.placeholder === \"--\" &&\r\n    data['Date-Returned-to-work'].year.placeholder === \"----\") {\r\n        show = false;\r\n    } else {\r\n        show = true;\r\n    }",
                "logic": [],
                "attributes": {},
                "widget": {
                    "type": ""
                },
                "reorder": false
            }
        ],
        "collapsed": false,
        "reorder": false,
        "properties": {},
        "customConditional": "",
        "logic": [],
        "attributes": {}
```

Basically, I want to make "show: false" when a user leaves a field with the default (placeholder) values. All help is appreciated. Changing JSON values like this is new-ish to me.

Comment: *Changing JSON values like this is new-ish to me* ... even if so, you cant just make up your own rules. ... E.g. `"key": "Date-Returned-to-work"` does not follow to reference it as `data['Date-Returned-to-work']`.

Comment: @GetSet so what would be a better way to reference it?

Comment: I would need more debugging details. At present your "Object B" looks mangled and malformed. That is, its not valid javascript. For example, `-validate` in `-validate: { .. }` is not a valid identifier for a property. Properties cannot begin with or even contain  `-` as that is a reserved word for subtraction.

Comment: This is why I also said you cant just make up your own rules and syntax

Comment: @GetSet I see the issue. I copied it from a different area that formatted it like that. I edited the original post to the proper format.

Comment: There's no `Date-Returned-to-work` property. I think you want `if (data.label == 'Date-Returned-to-work' && data.fields.data.placeholder == '--' && ...)`

Comment: Awesome. This is a being help!